# React Native Firebase Crashlytics Deobfuscation

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I have integrated crashlytics using [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage), and i have uploaded all the required dSYMs into the console. So, the crashes are shown, but they are obfuscated and they can't be tracked down in this format.

```
Fatal Exception: RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.code')

This error is located at:
    in O
    in B
    in p
    in RCTView
    in Portal.Host
    in c
    in h
    in s
    in v
    in u
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in o
0  CoreFoundation
```

I had no success trying to de-obfuscate them somehow.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a stacktrace on the Crashlytics dashboard, or is it just a log? Could you attach a screenshot of the console where the stacktrace for the crash is displayed? Finally you can check the RN+Firebase github issues for anything similar to this: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Javascript exception, and you have probably copied the raw text. If you check in the formatted text, it will look like something like this:

```
Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.code') This error is located at: in O in B in p in RCTView in Portal.Host ..., stack: value@1451:1379 value@1451:1558 value@1764:2262 value@1764:1616 Tl@161:77714
```

This format matches the JSC (react-native) stack trace and you can use a tool like [stack-beautifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stack-beautifier) to parse it in a humanly readable form. The tool also has a nice documentation of the process needed to reach a humanly readable format. In short, you will need to:

1. Find or re-create the source maps using react-native bundle from the needed branch, again, detailed steps in the tool’s documentation on how to do this
2. Extract the JSC stack trace into a new txt file, add new lines in the proper places (i.e. first one goes after "...stack:")
3. Run the tool with all of the above input and you should get what you are looking for