# Firebase Crashlytics React Native: Not able to understand stacktrace

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

[image]

So I am getting this [see Image] as a stacktrace after integrating `react-native-firebase` and I am able to understand it. Message is correct "undefined is not an object". But Line Numbers are missing. This is no file name.

If there is any way I can upload react native bundle to firebase to make it more understandable.

Already read
[React Native Firebase Crashlytics Deobfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62214336/react-native-firebase-crashlytics-deobfuscation)

Can't do this for every crash.

If the functionality is not available on firebase please comment. If the integration was wrong please let me know.

I am using these versions

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.0.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^12.0.0".
```

And

```
 firebaseCrashlytics {
                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }
```

is enabled for release flavour.

Checking these issues on release build.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459572/crashlytics-stacktrace-in-firebase-logs-is-not-readable